# ¿Cómo leer archivo csv con php y comprobar su formato y contenido?

Tags: php, csv

Estoy intentando importar contactos a través de un archivo cvs, ya tengo el código principal que lee dicho archivo. Lo he obtenido de la documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
public function importarContactos(){
    $fila = 1;
        if (($gestor = fopen($_FILES['archivoimportar']["tmp_name"], "r")) !== FALSE) {
            $contador =  0 ;
            while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                if($contador>0){
                    $numero = count($datos);
                    echo "$numero  campos en la línea $fila: \n";
                    $fila++;
                    for ($c=0; $c < $numero; $c++) {
                        echo $datos[$c] . "\n";
                    }
                }
                $contador++;
            }
            $contador = $contador - 1;
            echo "$contador registros en total";
            fclose($gestor);
        }
}
```

Lo que necesito es validar los encabezados de dicho archivo (la primera fila), que solo contenga 4 columnas de nombre: Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2, Email, Celular.

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente (agregar otro if dentro del while, pero no entra nunca en la vida):

```
public function importarContactos(){
    $fila = 1;
    $bandera= false;
        if (($gestor = fopen($_FILES['archivoimportar']["tmp_name"], "r")) !== FALSE) {
            $contador =  0 ;
            while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                if($contador==0 && $datos[0]=='Nombre'){
                    $bandera = true;
                }

                if($contador>0){
                    $numero = count($datos);
                    echo "$numero  campos en la línea $fila: \n";
                    $fila++;
                    for ($c=0; $c < $numero; $c++) {
                        echo $datos[$c] . "\n";
                    }
                }
                $contador++;
            }
            $contador = $contador - 1;
            echo "$contador registros en total";
            fclose($gestor);
        }
}
```

La pregunta en concreta es esa: ¿Cómo valido que el encabezado (o formato del archivo) cumpla con mis especificaciones? Esto para validar posteriormente el tipo de datos de cada columna pero eso ya tengo gran parte resuelta.

**ACTUALIZADO**:

```
public function importarArchivo($archivo){
            $fila = 1;
            /* El contenido esperado dentro de cada una de las cabeceras */
            $cabeceras = [
                'Nombre',
                'Apellido1',
                'Apellido2',
                'Email',
                'Celular',
            ];
            /* Abrimos el archivo igual que haces en tu código original */
            //$gestor = fopen($_FILES['archivoimportar']['tmp_name'], 'r');
            if (($gestor = fopen($archivo["tmp_name"], "r")) !== FALSE) {
                $contador =  0;
                /* Leemos por ahora únicamente el primer registro */
                $datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ',');
                /* Comprobamos:
                     * ¿había primer registro?
                     * ¿coinciden el número de campos?
                     * ¿falta algún elemento de las cabeceras esperadas?
                */
                if (
                    $datos === false
                    || count($cabeceras) != count($datos)
                    || count(array_diff_assoc($cabeceras, $datos)) > 0
                ) {
                    /* Si llegamos a este punto es porque todo ha ido bien */
                    while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
                        /* Leer datos de los registros */
                        if($contador>0){
                            $numero = count($datos);
                            echo "$numero  campos en la línea $fila: \n";
                            $fila++;
                            for ($c=0; $c < $numero; $c++) {
                                echo $datos[$c] . "\n";
                            }
                        }
                        $contador++;
                    }
                     $contador = $contador - 1;
                    echo "$contador registros en total";
                    fclose($gestor);
                }else{
                    /*El archivo no cumple con el formato establecido*/
                    echo 1;
                }


            }else{
                /*Ocurrió un problema al abrir el archivo*/
                echo 0;
            }

        }
```

Las cabeceras siguen sin validarse:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo lo he cambiado para testear lo tengo de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del contenido del CSV que envías? Es para cotejar los campos que esperas con la información que envías.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes comprobar uno a uno el contenido del primer registro de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
/* El contenido esperado dentro de cada una de las cabeceras */
$cabeceras = [
    'Nombre',
    'Apellido1',
    'Apellido2',
    'Email',
    'Celular',
];
/* Abrimos el archivo igual que haces en tu código original */
$gestor = fopen($_FILES['archivoimportar']['tmp_name'], 'r');
if ($gestor !== false) {
    /* Detectamos presencia de BOM extrayendo los primeros 3 bytes del archivo */
    if (fgets($gestor, 4) != "\xef\xbb\xbf") {
        /* Si no hay BOM volvemos al comienzo del archivo */
        fseek($gestor, 0, SEEK_SET);
    } 
    $contador =  0;
    /* Leemos por ahora únicamente el primer registro */
    $datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ',');
    /* Comprobamos:
         * ¿había primer registro?
         * ¿coinciden el número de campos?
         * ¿falta algún elemento de las cabeceras esperadas?
    */
    if (
        $datos === false
        || count($cabeceras) != count($datos)
        || count(array_diff_assoc($cabeceras, $datos)) > 0
    ) {
        /* Decidir qué hacer en caso de que no sean las cabeceras esperadas */
    }
    /* Si llegamos a este punto es porque todo ha ido bien */
    /* Aquí debe ir el resto de tu código original */
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        /* Leer datos de los registros */
    }
}
```

Hago uso de [`array_diff_assoc()`](http://php.net/array_diff_assoc) en vez de [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) porque el primero comprueba que los índices numéricos coincidan (se mantenga el orden de los elementos) pero el segundo no.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, he actualizado mi pregunta y adaptado tu respuesta a mis necesidades, sin embargo, aún así siguen si validarse, ya lo he intentado de otras maneras comparando campo por campo (con 5 ifs) pero de igual manera sigue sin validarse, justo no entiendo que sucede. Ojalá me puedas seguir ayudando. Compartí capturas de pantalla. Gracias.  Nota: En el excel he cambiado el nombre de los campos para testear la validación.

Comment: Listo ya lo solucioné, he cambiado la condición a esto if (
           $datos === false
           || count($cabeceras) != count($datos)
           || count(array_diff_assoc($cabeceras, $datos)) == 1
       )

Comment: Si te funciona comparando con 1 es porque algún campo está mal. Necesito el contenido del CSV en texto, copiar y pegar, y no una captura de pantalla. Es muy importante porque parece que hay un espacio en blanco o algo que hay de más. Por ejemplo, si el encabezado termina por una coma significa que hay un campo más al final cuyo contenido es una cadena vacía (es un ejemplo de por qué necesito el copia/pega del CSV).

Comment: ¿De verdad? Mira, el archivo que estoy utilizando es este: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10YEqDyklYydMijby3RRtwcWlLXP3NmvJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Vale, he detectado que tu archivo es UFT8 con BOM, por lo que hay que detectarlo y eliminarlo.

Comment: Si está bien, muchas gracias muy amable.

Comment: He detectado algo (que desconosco, pero puede ser una pista), antes del if en cuestión hago un echo json_enconde($datos)  y me arroja caracteres extraños antes del "Nombre", temo que de ahí proviene el asunto, sin embargo, no se de donde salen esos caracteres porque en el excel no hay espacios vacíos. https://prnt.sc/lwncli

Comment: Eso es el [BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes) :)

Comment: Comprueba ahora si te funciona mejor.

Comment: ¿Entonces solo agrego este if?     /* Detectamos presencia de BOM extrayendo los primeros 3 bytes del archivo */
       if (fgets($gestor, 4) != "\xef\xbb\xbf") {
           /* Si no hay BOM volvemos al comienzo del archivo */
           fseek($gestor, 0, SEEK_SET);
       }

Comment: Vale, con ese cambio, tengo que actualazar el if a esta forma if (
           $datos === false
           || count($cabeceras) != count($datos)
           || count(array_diff_assoc($cabeceras, $datos)) == 0
       )  ahora parece que ya funciona! :) Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sí. Con esas líneas extraigo los primeros tres bytes del archivo (pongo `4` porque es `4 - 1` bytes lo que lee) y si no son un BOM de UTF-8 "rebobina" el archivo al principio.

Comment: ¡De nada! ¡Un placer! :)